# Why Unity3D can't change a simple GUITexture by string?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i trying to change a GUITexture from a GameObject and nothing happend.
It try to load a texture 2D but erase a texture from GUITexture and dont load a new one, like code below.

```
public GameObject materialToChange;
public GameObject imageEnviroment;

void OnGUI()
{
    GUI.skin = btGoBack;

    if( GUI.Button(..., "")  )
    {
        if( materialToChange )
        {

            Debug.Log( "Enviroment Name: "+ materialToChange.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.name );
            // This show like this "Enviroment Name: nameOfTextureString (Instance)"

            Texture2D newTexture = Resources.Load<Texture2D>( materialToChange.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.name );

            imageEnviroment.GetComponent<GUITexture>().texture = newTexture;

            Debug.Log("Texture Name is?? "+ newTexture.name );
            // Here i receive this "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object"
        }
    }
}
```

I try to put path where texture is and i have same NULL REFERENCE.
Is there a way to change only GUITexture texture ?
Thanks for yours patience and helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GREAT problem is the UNITY put a " (Instance)" string to the name of the texture.name.
If UNITY put this ONLY on debug to we see that is a instance.
So i have to remove this STRING using this:

```
Debug.Log( "Enviroment Name: "+ materialToChange.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.name.Replace(" (Instance)","") );
```

And then the name was correct and now change my texture!
Pretty annoying and shame of Unity doing this.... But now its fixed.
Thanks for your answer @mx-d

Comment: I am glad I could be of help

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you are planning to only change the GUITexture it would be beter to have a

```
public UITexture;
```

and assign this instead.

But back to the issue of the day, You are trying to assign a *material* name to a *Texture*. This explains why you are getting nullreference because **the texture is never assigned**. So instead of

```
materialToChange.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.name
```

you will want something like

```
materialToChange.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.mainTexture.name;
```

also make sure that this texture is located in your  *Assets/Resources* (case sensitive) folder else the Resources.Load will not work for you to begin with

Comment: add a .mainTexture doesnt help, same error. A GUITexture is inside a gameobject, because i need to change and animate ( animate is ready ). So thats why i need to change only this GUITexture inside ( component ) a GameObject. Thanks!